# Does the Eilenberg Moore Construction Preserve fibrations?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monads, fibration

Say we have a Grothendieck fibration $p : E \to B$ and a monad $T$ on $B$ and a lift $T'$ of $T$ to $E$, i.e. a monad on $E$ such that $pT' = Tp$ and $p$ preserves $\eta, \mu$.

Then because the Eilenberg–Moore construction is functorial, we have a morphism $EM(p)$ from $T'\text{-}Alg$ to $T\text{-}Alg$. Is $EM(p)$ generally a fibration? If not, under what conditions is $EM(p)$ a fibration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $C$ be a 2-category and $Mnd(C)$ the 2-category of monads in $C$. As explained by Street in [the formal theory of monads](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(72)90019-9), the Eilenberg-Moore construction is right 2-adjoint to the inclusion 2-functor $C \to Mnd(C)$ sending an object to the identity monad on it. Therefore it preserves 2-limits.

A [fibration in a 2-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/fibration+in+a+2-category) may be defined in terms of certain 2-limits (namely slice categories) and adjoints, and so is preserved by any 2-functor preserving 2-limits, and in particular by the Eilenberg-Moore construction.

Thus it's sufficient for $p$ to be a fibration object in the 2-category $Mnd(C)$.

Comment: So just need to figure out what a fibration object in Mnd is then.

Comment: Fibrations can be detected by homming in, so one answer will probably be a tautological one: $p: E \to B$ is a fibration if $Mnd(C)(X,E) \to Mnd(C)(X,B)$ is a fibration for all monads $X$, which will probably reduce in the case $C = Cat$ to the induced map of Eilenberg-Moore objects being a fibration.

Comment: I think it would probably be easier to understand fibrations in Mnd(C) using the characterization of fibrations in terms of limits.  Since the forgetful functor $\mathit{Mnd}(C)\to C$ also preserves limits (when C has Kleisli objects it has a left adjoint), being a fibration in Mnd(C) just means being a fibration in C together with the extra structure that the universal lift-assigning functor and transformation lift to Mnd(C).  Then just work out what that means explicitly.

Comment: When you say the forgetful functor $Mnd(C) \to C$ do you mean the inclusion $C \to Mnd(C)$ that picks the identity monad instead? That's what it looks like it says in Street.

Comment: Oh wow! Yes, thanks for catching that!